# MySQL / Laravel / Eloquent: Select rows that exist in 2 tables

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a `users` table, and 2 pivot tables (`user_locations`, `user_roles`) that allows users to associate with multiple "locations" and "roles". What's the best way to select users that belong to, say, `New York` (a location) **and** `Manager` (a role)?

Columns in each table:

Table `users` => `id`, `name`

Table `user_locations` => `user_id`, `location_id`

Table `user_roles` => `user_id`, `role_id`

So, for example, I'd like to get a list of users that are associated with location_id `100`, and role_id `200`

I hope I'm explaining my goal clearly. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the relationships setup correctly in your users model you could do:

```
$new_york_managers = User::whereHas('locations', function($q) {
    $q->where('id', 100);
})->whereHas('roles', function($q) {
    $q->where('id', 200);
});
```